# unexpected interaction between macroexpand-1 and macrolet

Tags: macros, common-lisp

Consider the following sequence of forms in Common Lisp (evaluations performed in SBCL 2.4.2 for Windows):

```
(defmacro double-g (x)
  (list (quote +) x x))

(macroexpand-1 (quote (double-g 3))) => (+ 3 3), T

(macrolet ((double-l (x) (list (quote +) x x)))
  (macroexpand-1 (quote (double-l 3))))
=> (DOUBLE-L 3), NIL
```

Can someone help me understand why the second and third forms evaluate to different results?

I expected the second and third forms to evaluate to the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem: you are trying to expand the macro in the wrong [*environment*](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_aa.htm). The `macrolet` defines a local macro, but `macroexpand-1` does not see it, because it does not get the lexical environment passed.

We'll modify the macro expander:

```
CL-USER 23 > (defmacro expand-1-form (form &environment env)
               (list 'quote (macroexpand-1 form env)))
EXPAND-1-FORM
```

Above defines a macro `expand-1-form`, which gets passed the *current environment*, which then is available via the variable `env`. The macro expands this form by using `macroexpand-1` and also passes the environment to it. The macro `expand-1-form` gets the environment automagically passed into the environment variable `env` (which we defined in the parameter list). The expansion is returned as a quoted form.

Now we can expand the local macro `double-l` using the macro `expand-1-form`:

```
CL-USER 24 > (macrolet ((double-l (x) (list (quote +) x x)))
               (expand-1-form (double-l 3)))
(+ 3 3)
```

Above expands the macro `expand-1-form`, passing the current environment. This then calls `macroexpand-1` with that environment.

We can also write it as nested `macrolet`s:

```
CL-USER 25 > (macrolet ((expand-1-form (form &environment env)
                          (list 'quote (macroexpand-1 form env))))
               (macrolet ((double-l (x)
                            (list (quote +) x x)))
                 (expand-1-form (double-l 3))))
(+ 3 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, and for cleaning up the formatting of the original post. This explanation was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[`macroexpand-1` and `macroexpand`](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mexp_.htm) need to know about the environment of a macro call in order to expand it, and they take an optional environment argument that can provide this context. By default these procedures use the [null lexical environment](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_aaca.htm).

[Macro lambda lists](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_dd.htm) allow the inclusion of an `&environment` parameter which is bound to an environment object representing the lexical environment of a macro call. You can use this to write macros that expand forms within their local environments:

```lisp
(defmacro macroexpand-local-1 (form &environment env)
  `,(macroexpand-1 form env))

(defmacro macroexpand-local (form &environment env)
  `,(macroexpand form env))
```

```
CL-USER> (macrolet ((double-l (x) `(+ ,x ,x)))
           (macroexpand-1 '(double-l 3)))
(DOUBLE-L 3)
NIL
CL-USER> (macrolet ((double-l (x) `(+ ,x ,x)))
           (macroexpand-local-1 '(double-l 3)))
(+ 3 3)
T
```

### Avoiding Trouble with Dynamic Extent

These notes attempt to shed some light on a subtlety relating to the macro environment objects associated with `&environment` parameters. I was caught out on this; hopefully those who read this won't be.

I had previously written the `get-lexenv` convenience macro to return a macro environment object:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defmacro get-lexenv (&environment env) `,env)
GET-LEXENV
```

I then used the returned environment object in a macro expansion call like this:

```lisp
CL-USER> (macrolet ((double-l (x) (list (quote +) x x)))
           (macroexpand-1 (quote (double-l 3)) (get-lexenv)))
(+ 3 3)
T
```

This appeared to work, but it is not guaranteed to work. Thanks to [@RainerJoswig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78215628/unexpected-interaction-between-macroexpand-1-and-macrolet#comment137915870_78220214) for pointing this out in comments. Rainer also linked to an [interesting discussion](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Issues/iss229_w.htm) about the matter.

A macro environment object bound to an `&environment` parameter has dynamic extent, which means roughly that it can only be referenced from within the form which binds it. In `get-lexenv` the dynamic extent of the environment object ends once the evaluation of the `get-lexenv` form has ended.

It appears that some Common Lisp implementations have treated macro environment objects as having *indefinite extent*, at least in some circumstances. According to the linked discussion, CMU Common Lisp was one such implementation, and SBCL has descended from that code base. Perhaps that is why this seemed to work in this instance.

In any case, this can not be relied upon.

Comment: I don't have sufficient reputation to upvote this answer, but thank you for the response, and the `get-lexenv` macro, that is quite handy.

Comment: this might not work, when the environment object has *dynamic extent*,  which some implementation might use. See for example the discussion here: https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Issues/iss229_w.htm Returning the environment from GET-LEXENV might then not work.

Comment: See https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_dd.htm

"The object that is bound to the environment parameter has dynamic extent." Which means the GET-LEXENV may or may not work.

Comment: @RainerJoswig -- thanks for pointing this out and for the interesting link. I thought about deleting my answer, but decided to update it (the new macro solution is essentially the same as yours) and include some discussion about the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure the new macroexpand-local will work, since you return the environment object via a list as a result. If the dynamic extent is macroexpand-local, then the object is leaving that extent. I know at least one implementation where it does not work.

Comment: See my `expand-1-form`, the environment object is not returned in any way. It is just temporarily passed downwards.

Comment: @RainerJoswig -- of course you are correct; updated

Comment: @RainerJoswig -- this might be a case where avoiding quasiquotes makes things more clear, as in your `expand-1-form`.